# Disable System Monitor from opening with Ctrl+Alt+Del

Tags: shortcut-keys, monitor, system, shortcuts

I disabled the default shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> for the log out settings, and I also commented out the "exec" portion in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.conf file.  But now when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, system monitor opens up even though I have no shortcut enabled for it to do that.

I tried googling for this but they all lead to pages to people who want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to open system monitor to mimic the Windows Task Manager.  I don't want system monitor to open but can't find a way to disable this.  This occurred in both 14.04 and 16.04.

Comment: I have the exact same question.  Can we disable that shortcut somewhere on Ubuntu 16.04?